# Dom based XSS discovering tool

Tags: javascript, security, url, dom, xss

For my studys i have to develope a web site that verify from a given url if this is vulnerable to DOM Based XSS and then print a report of what it found, i already read a lot of article and specifically this ones [Description of xss](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/DOM_Based_XSS) [Documentation on prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) [Doc on prevention of DOM based](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

but i'm stucked in a point, which is :

> How can i inspect/analyze the dom of a page from a given url, from my web site (html/js/jquery)

Comment: Before putting a mark down to the question, please ask me where i can be more precise, since i'm new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents this.

You'll need to find a different approach.

Comment: To be more precise the idea that came accross me was to write a local script that will download the source-code of the web-page from the given url, parse it to find flaws, and then send back to my website datas about that

Comment: @Eros-Capo — Well, that's fine, but your local script can't be written in browser-side JS because the same origin policy will block your attempt.

Comment: Exactly, so, since SOP, i can't inspect from browser-side, but i can in any other way that isn't  browser-side?